# I am trying to connect to AWS S3 after setting the bucket policy to force SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using a bucket policy to force SecureTransport:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Id": "S3SecureTransportPolicy",
     "Statement": [
     {
     "Sid": "ForceSSLOnlyAccess",
     "Effect": "Deny",
     "Principal": {
         "AWS": "*"
     },
     "Action": "s3:*",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
     "Condition": {
         "Bool": {
             "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
}}}]}
```

This works:

```
aws s3 ls
```

But this doesn't

```
aws --profile default s3 cp "New Text Document.txt" s3://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/dir/
```

Could someone tell me if I can still use the AWS CLI in Windows to upload files to S3 now that I am forcing SSL? If so, how?

My IAM account access / secret key has admin access. Using CloudBerry Explorer with the SSL checkbox checked works.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the error reported when you do `s3 cp`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how you are specifying your bucket in the command line.

For the AWS CLI do not specify a URL such as `s3://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/dir/` instead specify the bucket and path like this `s3://mybucket/dir/`

Comment: Oddly enough the other command format had been working, but your suggestion works. Thank you!